# Just not getting MVC (like backbone.js)

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, backbone.js

I'm reasonably comfortable with javascript and php; I'd say I'm an intermediate. I'm starting a new project that really does need to be built in something like an MVC framework. I've been looking into backbone.js, but for some reason the logic is just not sticking. I've poked around with OOPHP and of course working with jQuery, a certain level of "objectness" is inherent... but I can't quite get my hands around the basic methodology of something like backbone.js.

Is there somewhere else I should start? A simpler MVC or maybe a good resource that I can work with that will help the concepts and methods stick?

It's just such a paradigm shift. Compared to all the procedural stuff I've done thus far, it really is like learning a new language.

Also, I won't be using a RESTful interface or anything, just good ole fashioned saving stuff to MYSQL via php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in learning the MVC approach using javascript, I would suggest to read [Javascript Web Applications](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018421.do). You will also find a chapter on Backbone.

Take also a look at [Backbone Patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/).

Comment: +1 nice one on backbone patterns, i did not know that site yet, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well,

technically backbone.js is a variant on the whole MVC concept. Backbone uses a model-view-collection concept rather than model-view-controller. where the view, takes over some work of what the controller in real mvc would do.

it's not a bad thing, in my opinion javascript was never even intended to do such a thing :)
and if you're not used to programming in MVC you might not even notice the difference.

though if you want to start with a few simple examples, around backbone.js i suggest you take a look at this website http://www.backbonetutorials.com/ which gives you a kickstart into building model-view-collection apps (as backbone does it). then when you grasp the concept, you can hop on to the [examples given on the backbone.js website](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples). especially the Todo Application which has also provided the annotated source of the object. it's a fully working simple application, which might give you an idea of how it should work rather than having these separated examples. but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: Yeah the MVC thing is just kicking my ass.

Comment: Yeah the MVC logic is just so foreign. It'll take a few attempts before it really clicks. I played with Knockout, and the MVVM approach was easier to digest. It seemed more... obvious? Intuitive? It might be "sloppier" coding to mix markup with scripting, but something about that method just made more sense to me.

Comment: well keep in mind that backbone.js isn't true MVC either, your code is rather tightly bound to your view. in fact i find myself writing lots of code into the view's where the actual views (the ones mvc would define) are more or less my templates that i render through my backbone views. i just don't want you to come out knowing everything about backbone, and thinking you know true MVC :), it's just another spin with it's own flavor, and for now i think it's doing it pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone is not an implementation of the MVC pattern.  It's better instead to think of it as a MV* implementation, where it has models, but no controller, and its views are often implemented as a combination of view, controller, and presenter, and there is no strict controller or presenter or viewmodel.  Understanding that is definitely the first thing to realize when feeling confused about backbone and trying to understand how to use it when referencing the MVC pattern.

The MVC, MVP, MVVM, and MV* patterns are difficult to truly grok with just reading an article or two, or with a simple example, and it seems like everyone has a similar yet slightly different idea of exactly what they are.

For a really really good discussion of MVP and MVC in relation to backbone, read Addy Osmani's article on developing backbone applications  [Here](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals).

But if you are simply concerned about how to use backbone, and feel like you have to be a MVC expert to do it correctly, then you're worrying about the wrong thing.  Instead, look at existing published backbone examples, follow those patterns, and as you add code to your view and model, keep the following points in mind for every piece of code you write:

1. Is this view specific code?  Then put it in the view.
2. Is this data specific code?  Then put it in the model.
3. Is this code about coordinating the view and model?  Tend toward putting that in the view.

A good guideline for # 1 and 2 above, is to not allow your model to reference the DOM at all, then put all the code you can in the model.  And only code that has to reference the DOM goes in the view.  If you try for that goal, and only violate it when it's obvious that the code is way more convoluted if you put it in the model, then you should be pretty good.